# Backgroundcolor of ExpandableListView while scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, background-color, expandablelistview

I have a problem with an ExpandableListView in my Android application. I've set a custom background color but while scrolling the list the color changes to black untill the scrolling has stopped. Is that normal or can you change the "onScrollColor"?

Comment: ajust set this attribute android:cacheColorHint =  rgb value of the backgroung you are using or "#fff"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this kind of problem and solved it using this property in my list XML `android:cacheColorHint = "#00000000"`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use a **`ViewHolder`** for reuse of your Views inside your getView Method

like in this example:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

the background to this is that Android trys to reuse the Views while scrolling and if you dont obey the Caching Rules (eg Using a ViewHolder like in the example) you have that described problem.